# HTML line-height issue when changing orientation on a mobile device

Tags: html, css

For our mobile site we have a toolbar fixed to the bottom of the screen. When the user switches orientation to landscape we're flipping the toolbar up and fixing it to the right side of the screen.

The problem is that whilst on the bottom it's easy to establish a **fixed line height** to ensure **images appear centred in each of the buttons**. But on the right the buttons will **vary in height** because the buttons are set using percentages.

**Question: Is there a solution whereby I can set the line-height dynamically without using script. Or, is there an alternative solution that doesn't involve losing my toolbar?**

**EDIT: I've created the following very basic Fiddle to illustrate what we're doing. If you drag the divider bar to the left of the results window wider and smaller you'll see how the effect is applied: http://jsfiddle.net/BMD8z/**

```
<div id="target-mobile">
    <div class="panel menu-track">track form</div>
    <div class="panel menu-phone"> <a href="tel:800-000-0000">Click to Call (800-000-0000)</a>

    </div>
    <div class="panel menu-search">Search box</div>
    <div id="toolbar">
        <div class="container_12 clearfix">
            <div class="grid_3"><a href="/ship" class="menu-ship button-red">ship</a>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_3"><a href="#" class="menu-track button-blue">track</a>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_2"> <a href="#" class="menu-phone">
                        <img src="http://bounce.nedoweb.com/Sitefinity/WebsiteTemplates/Default/App_Themes/Default/Images/mobile/icon-phone.png" alt="Click here to call us" /></a>

            </div>
            <div class="grid_2"> <a href="#" class="menu-search">
                        <img src="http://bounce.nedoweb.com/Sitefinity/WebsiteTemplates/Default/App_Themes/Default/Images/mobile/icon-search.png" alt="Click here to search the site" /></a>

            </div>
            <div class="grid_2"> <a href="#" class="menu-menu">
                        <img src="http://bounce.nedoweb.com/Sitefinity/WebsiteTemplates/Default/App_Themes/Default/Images/mobile/icon-menu.png" alt="Click here for the site menu" /></a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel menu-menu clearfix">
    <ul>
        <li>menu 1</li>
        <li>menu 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: Can you please show some code that demonstrates the issue so we can accurately help you?

Comment: Hi Wesley, I've added some code along with a Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply different CSS rules to your content depending on device orientation using media queries.

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    // portrait styles
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    // landscape styles
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thibauts, but the problem is not with applying different media queries. we're already doing that, it's more a case of the portrait mode being able to use a fixed-height line-height whereas landscape you can't. I'll be editing my post to demonstrate

Comment: Looking forward to you edit as I think I had (and solved) the same problem.

Comment: just added the edit with a Fiddle example. Main thing is that the buttons on a horizontal toolbar work great because you know exactly what the line height is, which is needed to vertically centre the button icon. A vertical toolbar is different because because the button height is variable.

Comment: I'm sorry, the code is too involved for the time I have at hand. Maybe try to strip it down to the core of the problem and one more charitable soul will give it a try